# Which tool to automate testing for desktop activities?

Tags: automated-testing, desktop-application

We are currently implementing and deploying a DLP (Data Loss Prevention) tool in my company, and I am trying to find a suitable tool / software to automate testing.

The tests are mostly related to desktop activities : create MS Office documents and apply MS Azure MIP classification ; try to exfiltrate sensitive documents across various channels (Teams, Outlook, internet upload) and insure that the DLP agent will pop-up a blocking Window for unauthorized operations.

Which tool do you think would be most suited for this use case ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of the popular tools that can be used to automate DLP testing for desktop activities:

1. TestComplete: A commercial tool that can be used to automate desktop and web applications.
2. Ranorex: Another commercial tool that can be used to automate desktop and web applications. It provides a drag-and-drop interface for creating automated tests and supports a wide range of desktop applications, including Office.
3. Selenium: It is an open-source tool for automating web applications. You can also use it to automate desktop applications with the help of third-party tools like WinAppDriver.
4. Appium: Another open-source library that works as an add-on with Selenium and can be used to automate mobile and desktop applications.

These can very well be good options to automate the creation of Office documents and testing the DLP agent's blocking capabilities when users try to exfiltrate sensitive documents through various channels.

Ultimately, the choice of tool will depend on your specific requirements and budget. It is recommended to evaluate multiple tools and conduct a proof-of-concept to determine the best fit for your organization.